# Cannot overload constructor in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm making a move-only equivalent of `std::function`. `move_function` contains a pointer to a base class, `move_function_base` which type erases the underlying functor type. `move_function_imp` inherits from `move_function_base` and holds the typed underlying functor. `move_function_imp` is defined like so:

```
template<class F, class ReturnType, class... ParamTypes>
class move_function_imp : public move_function_base<ReturnType, ParamTypes...> {

  typename std::remove_reference<F>::type f_;

public:
  virtual ReturnType callFunc(ParamTypes&&... p) override {
    return f_(std::forward<ParamTypes>(p)...);
  }
  explicit move_function_imp(const F& f) : f_(f) {}
  explicit move_function_imp(F&& f) : f_(std::move(f)) {}

  move_function_imp() = delete;
  move_function_imp(const move_function_imp&) = delete;
  move_function_imp& operator=(const move_function_imp&) = delete;
};
```

When I use this I get an error that the constructors cannot overload each other. What am I doing wrong? The full code is located [here](http://ideone.com/0U9Mhx).

---

*edit: error pasted from ideone link*:

```
prog.cpp: In instantiation of ‘class move_function_imp<main()::__lambda0&, void>’:
prog.cpp:39:30:   required from ‘move_function<ReturnType(ParamTypes ...)>::move_function(F&&) [with F = main()::__lambda0&; ReturnType = void; ParamTypes = {}]’
prog.cpp:62:38:   required from here
prog.cpp:20:12: error: ‘move_function_imp<F, ReturnType, ParamTypes>::move_function_imp(F&&) [with F = main()::__lambda0&; ReturnType = void; ParamTypes = {}]’ cannot be overloaded
   explicit move_function_imp(F&& f) : f_(std::move(f)) {}
            ^
prog.cpp:19:12: error: with ‘move_function_imp<F, ReturnType, ParamTypes>::move_function_imp(const F&) [with F = main()::__lambda0&; ReturnType = void; ParamTypes = {}]’
   explicit move_function_imp(const F& f) : f_(f) {}
            ^
prog.cpp:19:12: error: ‘move_function_imp<F, ReturnType, ParamTypes>::move_function_imp(const F&) [with F = main()::__lambda0&; ReturnType = void; ParamTypes = {}]’, declared using local type ‘main()::__lambda0’, is used but never defined [-fpermissive]
```

Comment: If `F` is `T&` (a reference), the first ctor will be `(T& const&)` which collapses to `(T&)` and the second one will be `(T& &&)` which collapses to `(T&)` as well. You need `remove_reference` here too.

Comment: IF `F` is a function type, you'd be asking for an rvalue function reference, like `R (&&)(T1, T2)`. I don't think such a type exists.

Comment: Also, using `ParamTypes&&` for `callFunc` is a very bad idea - if you specify `<void(int)>` for example, `callFunc` will be `void callFunc(int&& p)`, thus only accept rvalue arguments. Just use `ParamTypes` without further modification (you can keep the `std::forward`ing to move by-value arguments).

Comment: @Xeo So I suppose the best thing to do would be to store the functor as ``F f_`` and only declare one constructor ``move_function_imp(F f) : f_(std::forward<F>(f)) {}``?

Comment: @dschatz: While that works, it also invokes an extra (unnecessary) move construction into the ctor-parameter.

Answer (score 1):

It took a little toying around but I got [this](http://ideone.com/1a8EDY)

Snippet for answer completeness.

```
template <class>
struct remove_reference_except_function {};

template <class R, class... Args>
struct remove_reference_except_function<R(&)(Args...)>
{
    typedef R(&type)(Args...);
};

template <class R, class... Args>
struct remove_reference_except_function<R(&)(Args......)> //varardic function
{
    typedef R(&type)(Args......);
};
//I dont think you can have an rvalue reference to a function? Or can you dereference a non-capturing lambda?
template <class T>
struct remove_reference_except_function<T &>
{
    typedef T type;
};

template <class T>
struct remove_reference_except_function<T &&>
{
    typedef T type;
}; 

template< class ReturnType, class... ParamTypes>
struct move_function_base{
  virtual ReturnType callFunc(ParamTypes... p) = 0;
};

template<class F, class ReturnType, class... ParamTypes>
class move_function_imp : public move_function_base<ReturnType, ParamTypes...> {

  //Using std::remove_reference on a normal function gives you an invalid type for declaring a variable. Hence the custom reference removal
  typename remove_reference_except_function<F>::type f_; 

public:
  virtual ReturnType callFunc(ParamTypes... p) override {
    return f_(std::forward<ParamTypes>(p)...);
  }
  explicit move_function_imp(const typename std::remove_reference<F>::type& f) : f_(f) {}
  explicit move_function_imp(typename std::remove_reference<F>::type&& f) : f_(std::move(f)) {}

  move_function_imp() = delete;
  move_function_imp(const move_function_imp&) = delete;
  move_function_imp& operator=(const move_function_imp&) = delete;
};
```

As people pointed out your main issue was the template parameters collapsing to the same type giving you the overload error, so I used the normal std::remove_reference to remedy that.

Also you had a rogue rvalue reference in the callFunc of move_function_imp.

I had to create a custom remove_reference for declaring f_ because if you removed the reference from a normally created function (ff in my example) you got a compile error.

Honestly I'm a little bug-eyed from working on it should anyone have corrections I'd be happy to hear them.